# Get typings for function arguments from a readonly array of arrays

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to implement a function that looks like Jest's `test.each` iterator:

```
// with "as const"
forEach([
    [ 1, 2, 3 ],
    [ "a", "b", "c" ],
] as const, (first, second, third) => {
    // ...
});

// without "as const"
forEach([
    [ 1, 2, 3 ],
    [ "a", "b", "c" ],
], (first, second, third) => {
    // ...
});
```

The goal here is to make arguments `first`, `second`, and `third` strongly typed: without `as const` they all should be `string | number`; with `as const` they should be respectively `1 | "a"`, `2 | "b"`, and `3 | "c"`. The actual implementation of this function is irrelevant and might not even make sense, given its name.

I came this close to actually achieve the desired effect (see [Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NBP5bW)):

```
// implementation is not needed
declare function forEach<
    Lists extends ReadonlyArray<ReadonlyArray<unknown>>,
>(
    lists: Lists,
    iterator: (...args: Lists[number]) => void,
): void;
```

<sub>*I also thought about going with whatever Jest's typings are, but [their approach](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/ac06427179651ede0401fbd1a8c7a5df376ed664/types/jest/index.d.ts#L50) is messy and fragile, I don't want to do this.*</sub>

The arguments are properly typed, but there are still compiler errors in both cases:

- with `as const`:

  > The type `readonly [1, 2, 3]` is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type `[first: 1 | "a", second: 2 | "b", third: 3 | "c"]`
- without `as const`:

  > Type `number[] | string[]` is not assignable to type `[first: string | number, second: string | number, third: string | number]`. Target requires 3 element(s) but source may have fewer.

**Is there a way to define the `forEach` function to satisfy both use cases?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to infer the types for both the cases separately. Here is the code.  I have added the explanation in the comments. Let me know if you need more explanation.

```
declare function forEach<
    Lists extends BaseLists,
>(
    lists: Lists,
    iterator: (...args: TypeUnion<Lists>) => void,
): void;

type BaseLists = ReadonlyArray<ReadonlyArray<unknown>>;

// for readonly lists (when used with as const)
type TypeUnionReadonly<Lists extends BaseLists> = Lists[number] extends readonly [...(infer T)] // infer the tuple type for every list
    ? [...T] // tuple type
    : never

type TypeUnion<Lists extends BaseLists> = Lists[number] extends (infer T)[]
    ? T[]
    : Lists[number] extends ReadonlyArray<any>
    ? TypeUnionReadonly<Lists>
    : never

// ====================
// non const examples
forEach([
    [ 1, 2, 3],
    [ "a", "b", "c" ],
], (first, second, third) => {
    // ...
});

forEach([
    [ 1, 2, 3, 4], // works
    [ "a", "b", "c" ],
], (first, second, third) => {
    // ...
});

// ====================
// const examples
forEach([
    [ 1, 2, 3],
    [ "a", "b", "c" ],
] as const, (first, second, third) => {
   // ...
});

forEach([
    [ 1, 2, 3, 4], // error- length is 4 in one list, also the argument list has 3 parameters
    [ "a", "b", "c" ],
] as const, (first, second, third) => {
   // ...
});

forEach([
    [ 1, 2, 3, 4], // error- length is 4 in one list even if argument list has 4 parameters
    [ "a", "b", "c" ],
] as const, (first, second, third, forth) => {
   // ...
});
forEach([
    [ 1, 2, 3, 4], // works
    [ "a", "b", "c", "d"],
] as const, (first, second, third, forth) => {
   // ...
});
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-PwAs5gAsbYRTUIdXjpYzlfrtYvjebkjbMg7XYwPfAeH7qKHI4CE9LU5Ms-nPo9EGwHASGawbBg0axti8aLsmK5pqe655oWLZIeeNZ1jW14tr8qwRt27adoRvavjm74wMOfhfpov5GP+C5Jsuq5IdmKFbru+49F8MCEAAtCMPBmKiiJsDuiL4HgCCjE+KwQEwOADgg5hvDwkEyfAZCrAW8B2LAMYgDoJ50GeVaYVeTa4SsbAEbJ97EbJpG8ORg6UZ+460T005zoxS4pohJnIZu27wHuOYIjx-GCagwnLMwoUSfAUkklG7LTFgiArDAZiqag6lKJpqziXpuivIZXzGbQpkXlhDaWbe1ngZGdkPiRL7OQOQ45ouqLud+tB0QxCZMf5a5scFnHhT0h4wMea4YRWtXlo2NbAOWVn4RBOb2Y+z59i5XW9L11EeXQg0+XEQA)

Comment: In `type TypeUnion`, the `extends (infer T)[]` predicate seems to include the `extends ReadonlyArray<any>`. I mean, isn't `ReadonlyArray<Item>` a subset of `Item[]`? If it is, do we ever evaluate the second predicate (`ReadonlyArray<any>`)? If we don't, how does it work then?  Please, excuse my confusion 

Comment: Also, on a separate note, [in the second-to-last example](https://tsplay.dev/NBPrnW), is there any chance to make the `fourth` parameter `4 | undefined`, and remove the error?

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky,  no, `ReadonlyArray<any>` is not a subset of `Array<any>`. So, `TypeUnion` works fine.

Comment: Could you please elaborate, what makes read-only array not a subset of an array? I’m trying to understand _why_ it works, not _whether_ it works.

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky, actually it's the other way round. `any[]` is a subset/subtype of `readonly any[]`. This because any array is assignable to a readonly array variable. but not vice versa. An array has other methods which mutate the array like- `push`, `pop`, `fill` etc while readonly array does not have those methods.